# Тrip, tour та cruise - подорож?

Tags: переклад, from-english

В англійській мові є такі слова:

**Тravel** - подорож

**Trip** - подорож (зазвичай коротка), коли ви їдете в інше місце та повертаєтеся.

**Journey** - подорож з пункту А в пункт Б або ж довга сухопутня подорож.

**Tour** - поїздка кудись з певною метою

**Cruise** - морська подорож

Такі перекладачі як [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/Journey) перекладають слова "Trip", "Journey" та "Тravel" як "подорож" чи "поїздка". Та цікаво чи є в українській мові слова які б означали "коротку подорож" чи "довгу подорож". Вирішив пошукати [синоніми](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6) до слова "подорож" і, здається, зараз вже знайшов деякі можливі відповідники:

**Тravel** - подорож

**Journey** - мандрівка

Але як бути із такими словами як "**Trip**", "**Tour**" (перекласти лише запозиченим "тур" чи використати слово "екскурсія") та "**Cruise**" (лише "круїз"? - саме такий варіант дає [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/Cruise))

Comment: Дешчо корисна цема [на лінґвофорумі](https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=29147).

Comment: Різниця між значеннями англійських слів: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/689/27

Comment: [Сіноніми](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/подорож)